# Using a constant connection with ExecutorService threads

Tags: multithreading, jdbc, executorservice

I have a task to create a standalone java application to do the following:

1. Parse a .csv file. (This would have about 3 million records)
2. For each record, insert ~15 rows in several DB table.
3. Output if the .csv record was successfully processed or not.

My current thought to design this is:

1. Read the .csv file (haven't given much thought to this step yet)
2. Create a work/ task object for each record in .csv. Put all these task objects in a Queue/ List.
3. Create a predefined number of threads (old school, not using the Executor framework)

Each thread would have the logic:

1. Create DB connection.
2. `if(getNextJobFromList() != null)` 
    `// Prepare and insert the statements in a batch update.`
3. Close DB Resources.
4. Give status for output

Time is a very big constraint here.

Now the questions:

1. Can I make this faster using the Executor framework? In my pseudo code, a thread keeps a DB connection for its lifetime. Can I do this in Executor framework?
2. Are there other ways to optimize this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Executor to do this. It doesn't sound like a great idea, you're going to overwhelm the database with work and most of your threads are going to spend time waiting around.

I think you'd be better off doing a bulk-import into the database (using SQL*Loader if you're using Oracle, other databases have similar tools), no multithreading required. Bulk copying is extremely fast, it can turn off constraint-checking and index-modification and just slurp up data. It is orders of magnitude faster than JDBC and if you want speed you should check it out.

Comment: So you're saying my program should just create a .csv file with all the data to be inserted, and then I should use SQL*Loader to load all this data to the database?

Comment: @Georgie: yes, that would seem like the fastest-performing solution to me.